# The missing part

Tags: riddle, visual

As time passes, I often ask myself how life came to be? Brute force? Randomization? Strict rules of the natural world?
We sequenced the genome and are reading now the story of humanity. Not the complete story, of course. Still, even at the prologue it's clear - we are not so different from each other.  A little bit wobbly, but imagine, If people are books, they would differ in every thousandst word or so..

You may ask, how all of this translates to more familiar concepts? What story do our genes tell?

Make yourself comfortable. The journey is about to start. Maybe, you'll discover something new? Or just have fun. Finding a solution or meaning is sweet, but not the grand purpose of it all. It's OK to just wonder through the problems of life finding interesting things.

This time, there are a lot of twists in the plot. You'll start with the code of life, go through different transformations and end up with a time piece.. The final answer is a brand.

Ready, steady, go!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 7 letter Brand you are looking for is

> **CHOPARD**!!

> If one converts (through transcription) the **TOP HALF** of the DNA sequence into an RNA sequence and translate the latter into a protein sequence detecting the start and stop codons you get [**MILLE MIGLIA**](https://www.chopard.com/en-intl/watches-men-mille-miglia). These are a collection of watches belonging to a brand of Swiss watches called [**CHOPARD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopard).

> [image]

The clues (apart from the obvious one in the last paragraph) in the puzzles that point to this maneuver are as follows:

1)

> *You may ask, how all of this translates to more familiar concepts?* The ‘translates’ here hints to the RNA into protein sequence translation. The ‘familiar concepts’ being the watch collection being spelt by the protein sequence.

2. 

> The ‘twists in the plot’ refers to us having to ‘twist’ or ‘reverse’ the order of the pairs since it is the **”BOTTOM HALF”** or the  “TEMPLATE STRAND” of the DNA sequence that is diagrammatically converted into RNA. Also the ’twists’ could be also referring to [Protein Folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_folding).

> <sup>* According to the OP ‘twists’ also refers to “the turns of the DNA strands in addition to all the transcriptions and translations necessary.”</sup>

> [image]

3. 

> The chemical compounds on the left and right are [**METHIONINE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methionine) and [**GLYCINE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycine) respectively. These are both **AMINO ACIDS** which belong to a **protein sequence** hinting at a DNA to protein sequence conversion. (The latter also appears as the codon GGU in the RNA sequence too).

Comment: well done :) with the "twists" I meant also the turns of the DNA strands in addition to all the transcriptions and translations necessary

Comment: No, just a poetic statement of how much we don't know about the code of life